# iterate and replace span at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have the following code that iterates over the `<span>` inside the `<div>`:

```
$('#recommendTextArea').children('span').each(function () {
    //mentionedFriends.push($(this).html()); 
    var mentionedFriendName = $(this).html();
    jQuery.each(friendsList, function () {
        if (this.name == mentionedFriendName) {
            var facebookId = '@[' + this.id + ']';
        }
    });
});
```

I essentially wanted to replace this `<span>` with the string of `facebookId`. Is such thing possible? If yes how?

Comment: Can you provide some HTML and also what exactly you want it to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replaceWith`.

```
$('#recommendTextArea').children('span').each(function () {
    var $span = $(this);

    //mentionedFriends.push($(this).html()); 
    var mentionedFriendName = $(this).html();
    jQuery.each(friendsList, function () {
        if (this.name == mentionedFriendName) {
            var facebookId = '@[' + this.id + ']';
            $span.replaceWith(facebookId);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**  If you need to deal with special characters, etc. You can do this instead:

```
$span.replaceWith($("<div>").text(facebookId).contents());
```

Comment: I don't think this works as facebookId is a string... I always get the error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: @[100005960863705]

Comment: It works just fine with a string.  I don't seem to be getting that exception.  Can you make a fiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/7hZrf/1/

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do something like `$(facebookId)`?  That would cause that error.

Comment: @adit no, see my jsfiddle.  Please create one of your own which displays the issue.

Comment: I added an edit for a solution to handle special characters, but I see no reason why this should be needed with `@`.